# Grabcut algo with mask throwing error

Tags: python, opencv, mask

Here is my code i read a mask  "newmask.png" and tried to apply this mask for segmenting the image "bill.jpg" the size of both mask and bill.jpg are equal and i am getting the following error: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

please help me if any one have any idea about this .

Thanks in advance....

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('bill1.jpg')
mask2 = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
rect = (50,50,450,290)
'''cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()

'''
# newmask is the mask image I manually labelled
newmask = cv2.imread('newmask.png',0)
# whereever it is marked white (sure foreground), change mask=1
# whereever it is marked black (sure background), change mask=0
mask2[newmask == 0] = 0
mask2[newmask == 255] = 1
plt.imshow(mask2,'gray'),plt.show()

mask2, bgdModel, fgdModel =     cv2.grabCut(img,mask2,None,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)

mask2 = np.where((mask2==2)|(mask2==0),0,1).astype('uint8')

img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems like your machine has not enough memory to perform grabcut. Try to free up RAM before running this code.

Comment: Thanks ! but  i tried  it and i got same error . I also tried to remove alpha channel of image before providing it to grabcut but again stuck in same problem